# Non-Conflicting Separator Token for a one-string List of HTTP Header Values?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, http-headers, appsettings

I'm usually just the client-side-slob on the other end evaluating the occasional header so I'm not sure what all the possible character conflicts are. Anyway, the plan is to have a .NET appSettings config file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add
        key="someWebServiceClassName"
        value="Cache-Control:No-Cache<separator?>Some-Other-Header:Some-Value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm aware of header values using commas, parens, pipes, * and no doubt many other characters, so what's a value I can do a string split or C#-equivalent to build a list to set headers with that's not likely to run into overlap with legit or popular custom header values? A traditional list separator like semis would be great but I'll bet those are pretty common in custom headers. Note: for now I'm using {|} which just seems kinda ew to me. A single-char separator would be nice.

Comment: Why not separate the headers into unique settings?  Or better yet, define a config section to handle your scenario.

Comment: Feels like that would get kinda messy and prone to overlap for like 30 web services. I'd rather have one service/one-name.

Comment: Still a semi-interesting question for somebody else maybe but I no longer need an answer to this as, yes, it does require custom config and I've decided custom config in .net 4.0+ is so bloated and overwrought that it's completely !@#%ing useless. Config file to dictionary should be a one-liner. How freaking  hard is it to provide that?

Comment: this looks pretty interesting, haven't tried it myself: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Dec/28/Building-a-better-NET-Application-Configuration-Class-revisited

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks for that. I can dodge the bullet on this issue but I bookmarked it for pre-empting confusion when I absolutely have to tangle with custom config again.